# Laurent series for $ f(z) = \frac{1} {(z-1)(z-2)} $ around $ z_{0} =0$ and $|z| <1$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Find the Laurent series for $ f(z) = \frac{1} {(z-1)(z-2)} $ around $ z_{0} =0$ and $|z| <1$. I tried by writing $\frac{1} {(z-1)(z-2)}$ as $ \frac{1} {z-2} - \frac{1} {z-1} $ but how do I find the laurent series for $ \frac{1} {z-2}$ where $|z|<1$? I can only find it for $|z|<2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $$\frac{1}{z-2}=-\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{1-\frac{z}{2}}=-\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\frac{z^n}{2^{n+1}},$$ via the geometric series (we assumed that $|z|<1,$ so we certainly  have that $|z/2|<1$).